# VS code: Visualize all full path without being cut (command line)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code and I'm getting the following error on the command console:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@primavera/ngcore/components/events/eventsChain.components.ts(51,19):
>   error TS2352: Type
>   'import("C:/PrjNET/Iridium/JSM/Mainline-Test/Products/Primavera.JasminStandard/Host/ClientApp/node...'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'import("C:/PrjNET/Iridium/JSM/Mainline-Test/Products/Primavera.JasminStandard/Host/ClientApp/node...'.

There is any why that I could see the part `'import("C:/PrjNET/Iridium/JSM/Mainline-Test/Products/Primavera.JasminStandard/Host/ClientApp/node...'` as the full path without being cut by the output console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the Screen Buffer Size width bigger in a command prompt Layout properties.

Right click the title bar, select properties, and go to Layout.

Making it bigger gives a scroll bar.